# Paging of Query Result Set

Tags: database, indexing, full-text-search

Greetings Overflowers,

I'm wondering if there is a way to query some kind of a database and only fetch a certain window in the full result set without having to actually go through them all.

For example, if I query my database and I want only results number 100 to 200, would the database fetch all the results (say 0 to 1000) that match my query and later on filter them to exclude any thing outside my specified window frame ?

Actually, I'm working on a full text search problem (not really relational db stuff).

So how about Google and other search engines, do they get full result then filter or do they have direct access to only the needed window frame ?

Thank you all !

Comment: I'm so sad, why no answers yet :(

Answer (score 0):

Your question is probably best answered in two parts.

- For a database (traditional, relational), a query that is executed contains a number of "where" clauses, which will cause the database engine to limit the number of results that it returns. So if you specify a where clause that basically limits between 2 values of the primary key,

  select * From table where id>99 and id<201;

you'll get what you're asking for.

- For a search engine, a query you make to get the results will always paginate - using various techniques, all the results will be pre-split into pages and a few will be cached. Other pages will be generated on demand. So if you want pages 100-200 then you only ever fetch those that are needed.

The option to filter is not very efficient because large data sources never want to load all their data into memory and slice - you only want to load what's needed.